# GitHub pages: jekyll site theme not applied despite setting it up

Tags: github, jekyll

I've recently built a blog by forking [Barry Clark's Jekyll Now](https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now). I edited my readme file and some of the other files to start customizing it. I also redirected my own domain name to this site. Everything seems to be working and building as expected, except for the theme choosing.

I tried using the theme chooser as explained [here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-jekyll-theme-to-your-github-pages-site-with-the-jekyll-theme-chooser/) and also tried switching to a remote theme by manually editing `_config.yml` ([docs here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-jekyll-theme-to-your-github-pages-site/)), but none of them seem to take effect and my blog keeps showing the default theme.

Any hints on what else I should check?

Comment: A link to your repo would be helpful..

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: delete your _layouts/default.html file.